# Asp.net Core API endpoint structure for mobile app backend

Tags: api, rest, xamarin.forms, asp.net-core-webapi, mobile-application

I have to create a mobile application using Xamarin Forms and Asp.Net Core API that shows currently running offers(deals), popular services etc on the home screen.

There are a few tables - CATEGORY, SERVICE, and OFFER. There can be one or more services for a certain category. The Web API endpoints are as follows:

```
/api/category (POST)
/api/category (GET)
/api/category/{id} (GET)
/api/category/{id}/service (GET)
/api/category (PUT)
/api/category (DELETE)
```

The endpoints are similar as above for service and offer. Kindly correct the above endpoint structure if it is wrong.

I have two questions:

1. In the SERVICE table, there is a column (BIT type in SQL Server) that signifies a service as a popular service. Not all services are popular. There can be a few services that are marked as popular services. What should be the endpoint structure to retrieve all popular services?
   `/api/service/{popular}` ?
2. Since the mobile app home screen will show both the currently running offers and the popular services -

a) So should I call two separate endpoints to get the both currently running offers and the popular services

```
/api/offers

/api/service/{popular}
```

b) OR should I create another endpoint for mobile app only that will club both the calls and return a single JSON response for each of those data points?

```
/api/PrepareHomeScreen
```

Comment: My opinion. 0) Endpoints are correct 1) popular services for a category: depends on the actual relationship in reality. But if you're actually adding a service to a category, rather than assigning a category to your service, I'd pick `/api/category/{categoryId}/service/popular`. Therefor you will need to add the `Order` property to your `[HttpGet]` attribute on your controller method. 2) Yes

Comment: hi @Pieterjan, thank you for reply. 1) all popular services to be displayed regardless of the category. 2) there are two questions in 2nd question. Your "Yes" is for which one? I have just edited my question as 2. a) and b)

Comment: Hi and thx for clearing up. 1) I'd agree with `/api/service/popular` 2) I'd pick option `a`. But change `offers` to singular `offer` for consistency. Why singular? Cz ASP.NET Core provides the `[controller]` notation, and its most common. Retrieving data through multiple api calls is generally more flexible, easier to reuse/extend, and by far not a significant load on the server. In large apps they'd consider combining api calls when there are 8 or more. In that case, since your controller methods do not contain any logic whatsoever, it's actually a piece of cake adding a new controller method